# What is the difference between a dom element originally in the code, versus one that is added later?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, when I take a block of html, remove it, and then add it to the same place that it came from, I can't perform operations on the elements. Any idea why?

Something like this:

```
<div id="container">

    <img src="img.png" id="img1" height="auto">
    <img src="img2.png" id="img2" height="auto">

</div>

<script>

    var imgWidth = 0;

    function getImageWidth() {

        imgWidth = $("#img1").width();

    }

    getImageWidth(); // this will run

    // but if I remove say both images, then add them back
    $("#img1, #img2").remove();

    var block = '<img src="img.png" id="img1" height="auto">' + '\n' +
                '<img src="img2.png" id="img2" height="auto">' + '\n';

    $("#container").append(block);

    getImageWidth(); // this will not run, but no errors are thrown either

</script>
```

Comment: How do you know `getImageWidth();` doesn't work? You have nothing happening in it besides a variable getting set and no code after it testing if anything happened. Also in order to get an images width you have to wait for it to load

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j6xhyow9/

Comment: @PatrickEvans right, I was using $(window).on("load", function() {... for my preloader. I might have to use it again perhaps.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, also I know because my version of the code doesn't work, and I realize the code above isn't what I'm having a problem with but the concept/structure is the same, my project is almost a thousand lines, I tried to simplify it on here. Maybe your thought on waiting to load is the answer.

Comment: @joehungjohn See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PatrickEvans, now the question is, can I nest $(window).on("load" statements, doesn't appear to be the case...

Comment: @joehungjohn Don't set the load event on the window, just do $("#img1").on("load", function () {}). That will fire once the image has been loaded.

Comment: @IgorBarsi thanks for that tip, the images are loading fast enough, I think the problem lies somewhere else although not relevant to this post. Thank you for the clarification, will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** Just wanted to highlight my comment below that sheds some light on the issue for anyone looking for more clarity.

Working with dynamically added images like this can be tricky due to the inherent async nature of the issue. The images need to be loaded before you can access their attributes. I would recommend using the jQuery load event (or attach the event via vanilla JS, if you decide to go the non jQuery route) to wait until the image is loaded.

```
$("#img1").on("load", function () {
  // logic here
});
```

If you decide to attach this event in your getImageWidth function, either pass a callback containing the logic you would like to execute on the width of the image once its loaded, or convert getImageWidth into a Promise and execute your logic once the promise resolves.

---

Just added some real image links to your Fiddle, swapping them when the removed DOM gets re-added so you can tell the new width gets read and logged, seems to be working fine in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/ibarsi/umxxbcpm/

Here's my script changes in-case the link dies.

```
var imgWidth = 0;

function getImageWidth() {
  imgWidth = $("#img1").width();
  return imgWidth
}

console.log("FIRST", getImageWidth());

$("#img1, #img2").remove();

var block = '<img src="http://blogmedia.jaludo.com/titter/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/cute-animals4.jpg" id="img1" height="auto">' + '\n' +
    '<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3a/a8/bd/3aa8bd1b9a1befe4fc77c1556e16a5f8.jpg" id="img2" height="auto">' + '\n';

$("#container").append(block);

console.log("SECOND", getImageWidth());
```

Comment: Yeah maybe I'm not waiting long enough for the images to load, I'm not implying that I'm guessing using setTimeout for example. I mean the first time around I wait for images to load with the .on("load" but not this time, maybe that's what I missed.

Comment: Thanks for your post, although it turns out this question doesn't really help me. I did a test and the images are loading fast enough.

Comment: @joehungjohn Definitely, working with dynamically added images like this can be tricky due to the inherent async nature of the issue. The images need to be loaded before you can access their attributes. I would recommend using .on("load") as you describe in your comment, then either passing a callback to your getImageWidth function containing the logic you would like to execute on the width of the image, or convert getImageWidth into a Promise and execute your logic once the promise resolves. I could update my fiddle if you'd find that helpful?

Comment: I'm okay on the update. I get the idea, except maybe the callback part... callbacks are something I'm still working like requestAnimationFrame for instance. Anyway, now I'm wondering if I should just reload the entire script/images. Again not relevant to this question/beyond scope. Thanks for adding the clarification.